# How can I display the line number for a printf statement in c?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
int main() {
int i, repeatName; // ints
char firstName[50]; // array to store users name

// get first name from user
printf("Please enter your first name: ");
scanf("%s", firstName);

// get amount of times user would like to repeat name
printf("How many times would you like to repeat your name?: ");
scanf("%i", &repeatName);

// tell user name has to be repeated at last one
if (repeatName < 1) {
    printf("The name has to be repeated at least one (1) time. Try again: ");
    scanf("%i", &repeatName);
}

// for loop to repeat name 'x' number of times
for (i = 0; i < repeatName; i++) {
    printf("%s \n", firstName);
}
}
```

For example: If the user wanted to display their name 3 times it would say:

```
Your name 

Your name

Your name
```

How can I get it to say:

```
Line 1 Your name

Line 2 Your name

Line 3 Your name
```

Comment: What is the criterion behind the line number? is it just the number of iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `i` variable in the loop as the line number

```
for (i = 0; i < repeatName; ++i)
    printf("Line %d %s\n", i + 1, firstName);
```

Be sure to add 1, because the loop index starts from 0. You want the first line to say "Line 1", not "Line 0", and so on.

**Edit**: When the line number is more than one digit, the output is not as pretty. To solve this, you can write

```
for (i = 0; i < repeatName; ++i)
    printf("Line %-6d%s\n", i + 1, firstName);
```

This makes the line number take up at least 6 characters, and makes the number be left-justified:

```
Line 1     this is my string
Line 2     this is my string
Line 3     this is my string
Line 4     this is my string
Line 5     this is my string
Line 6     this is my string
Line 7     this is my string
Line 8     this is my string
Line 9     this is my string
Line 10    this is my string
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking to do. Appreciate the edit also.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that automatically, as far as I know. But you can make your i variable in the for loop act as a line counter too, since for each iteration you print a line:

```
// for loop to repeat name 'x' number of times
for (i = 0; i < repeatName; i++) {
    printf("Line %d %s \n", i + 1 /* Lines are not 0 based */ , firstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the loop index when you're printing:

```
for (i = 0; i < repeatName; i++) {
    printf("Line %d %s \n", i+1, firstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main() 
    {
    int i, repeatName; // ints
    char firstName[50]; // array to store users name

    // get first name from user
    printf("Please enter your first name: ");
    scanf("%s", firstName);

    // get amount of times user would like to repeat name
    printf("How many times would you like to repeat your name?: ");
    scanf("%i", &repeatName);

    // tell user name has to be repeated at last one
    if (repeatName < 1) {
        printf("The name has to be repeated at least one (1) time. Try again: ");
        scanf("%i", &repeatName);
    }

    // for loop to repeat name 'x' number of times
    for (i = 1; i <= repeatName; i++) {
        printf("Line %d Your name %s \n",i,firstName);
    }
    }
```